# Replace git master with branch (as in nuke master completely and have only the branch, NOT some individual commit)

Tags: git, gitlab

I made a branch off the master to develop a fork from a codebase. Now I'm done and I don't want to retain the original codebase.

How do I get rid of the head and replace it entirely with my branch? I'm using Gitlab if that's relevant. Both head and branch are mine, i.e. under my account, and nobody else is working on it.

Comment: When you say _head_, what do you mean? HEAD (uppercase) has a very special meaning in git and I want to be sure of what you mean with head with lowercase.

Comment: Ok, the master branch.

Comment: There's nothing special in Git about the name `master`. (Well, that's not 100% true, but it's true in spirit, as it were. The list of minor special cases for `master` won't fit in a comment. You *can* just *delete* the branch name `master` entirely if you like, though.) See [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61429954/1256452) for a practical recipe for what we both think you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do exactly? Take all the first n revisions that you didn't work on and squash them into *your* first revision?  If that's the case, find your very first revision that you worked in and create a branch on it. Say, `first`.

```
git checkout -b first the-id-of-your-first-revision
```

Now we will create a very first revision of another branch with this content:

```
git checkout --orphan=temp
git commit -m "first revision"
```

And now we replicate all the revisions between first and master on top of temp

```
git cherry-pick first..master
```

If you like the results, place master over here:

```
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git branch -D first temp #delete the other branches that we used
```

Done!

Comment: I was reworking a project. Being unfamiliar with git, I added the original code as the master branch, and made a separate branch to do my changes. All my changes are in the separate branch and the master is as it was when I took it up (an MPL licensed project). So now I want to get rid of the master cos it has nothing of value to me and retain just the branch. Does your answer help with that?

Comment: I think that recipe is what you want.